# find top 10 countries according to one column, get grouped barchart according to another (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, visualization

So, I have a df which comes from a Kaggle survey. The columns I am interested in are :

| country | gender | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Woman | 5612 |
| Germany | Man | 5613 |
| USA | non-binary | 5614 |
| India | Man | 5615 |

What I want to do now is plot a grouped bar chart of the top 10 countries (meaning top number of participants in the survey) showing the gender distribution of each top 10 country.

I managed to get a result close to what I want:

```
data_gender = df.groupby(['country', 'gender']).count().sort_values('id', ascending=False).reset_index()
data_gender.head()

fig = px.histogram(data_gender, x='county_residence', y="id",
             color='gender', barmode='group', height=400)
fig.show()
```

It results in exactly what I want: several bars representing the different gender categories per country.

[plot I get with code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzwbQ.png)

BUT I just can't figure out how to only show the plot for the top 10 countries of participant count.

It did find out which countries are in the top 10 with:

```
dftop10 = df.groupby(['country']).size().to_frame('count').sort_values('count', ascending = False).reset_index()
```

and also like so:

```
df_top10 = df.value_counts("county_residence")
top10 = df_top10.head(10).index.tolist()
genders = df[df['county_residence'].isin(top10)].groupby('gender').count()['id']
```

But I am running down dead ends. When I get to find the top 10 countries, I loose the info about each gender category. How can I

1. find the top 10 countries by overall participant count
2. get a subset of the data with all data on only those countries with counts for each gender category per country
3. and then with that run that plot code again?

I have been trying to figure this out for hours now. Please help me solve this :)

Comment: Have you tried adding `.head(10)` before `reset_index()` while creating `data_gender`? Like so: `data_gender = df.groupby(['country', 'gender']).count().sort_values('id', ascending=False).head(10).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While identifying the countries, you can pick just the first 10 rows using `[:10]`. While plotting, filter the data_gender column to show only those countries. That should do it...

```
data_gender = df.groupby(['country', 'gender']).count().sort_values('id', ascending=False).reset_index()

## Pick the first 10 rows only using [:10]
dfTop10=df.groupby(['country']).size().to_frame('count').sort_values('count', ascending = False).reset_index()[:10]

## Filter data_gender to show only countries in dfTop10 using .isin
fig = px.histogram(data_gender[data_gender['country'].isin(dfTop10['country'])], x='country', y="id",
             color='gender', barmode='group', height=400)
fig.show()
```

**Output with random data**

[image]

Comment: Great! I didn't know I could adjust the code for the figure like that. Thank you!